# Web app that synchronizes third-party app DB (via REST API) with SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, web-applications, synchronization, database-replication

Common replication question with seemingly a slightly different scenario.

In short, I'm trying to develop a C# web app that will link up a third party CRM application (via oAuth and its REST API) with a users remote data server (mySQL/SQL Server) and keep it synchronized.

User logs on, sets up an oAuth connection to the third party CRM, enters their SQL login credentials to their local server, clicks "GO".  My app then creates a fresh database on their server, makes an initial dump of data into said server from CRM via REST API, and then keeps it bi-directionally synchronized moving forward.

I understand this is a non-trivial undertaking however I'm just wondering if there are any tools/frameworks (such as SymmetricDS perhaps) that I should be looking at so that I don't reinvent the wheel and expedite the development.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) is intended for this purpose.  I don't know of any ready-made replication tool for MySQL.

Comment: And then, if I read this correctly, I'd have to code up a custom provider to talk to the REST API?

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood your requirements.  Replication works from one SQL Server to another, and you would need more control of the CRM database than you would get through an API.  Unless you are far ahead of me with that custom provider idea.  Sorry if I put you on the wrong track.

Comment: Yes, although I would have ADO access to my remote DB, my only communication to the third party CRM database is through a REST API.